# How does a NAT router obtain its IP address?

Tags: routing, dhcp, nat

I have a question about DHCP and NAT.

I know NAT translates local IP addresses and ports into a single IP address and specific ports that can be used to communicate with the Internet.

I also know DHCP is used to assign or re-use an unused IP address to a computer that connected to the network.

How does NAT obtain its single IP address? Does it use DHCP?

Comment: I'm curious as to why people are voting to close this question ?

Comment: I have no idea too. Happens to me a lot in stack. I don't understand if I did something wrong or the community doesn't like my questions.

Comment: The question was difficult to understand before it was edited.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

NAT and DHCP are totally independent technologies, which do not rely on each other at all.

The first concept to understand is one of network segments - simplifying slightly, all IP addresses in the same IP range are in the same segment.  A DHCP server listens on a given segment for requests for an IP address and offers it when asked.  A DHCP server needs to listen on the same interface as the segment is on - thus it can run on a computer with a single network card, or on a router (in a home network it would typically run on the router, serving addresses on the LAN network).

On a typical home router NAT is run on the WAN interface, and relables packets leaving the network with the external IP address.  It holds a translation table so it knows which internal machine requested what.  In this way its possible for a single real-world IP address to be shared between multiple workstations.

Your question "when I connect two different computers they both get different external IP's. How can this happen? Shouldn't my router be NAT since it protects my local IP Address?" presents something of a curveball.  The answer is yes, in a home network, any devices behind NAT would typically share a single external IP address.

There are a few possibilities why you are getting different IP addresses, including -

1. Your provider is using Carrier Grade NAT, and and is, in effect doing double-nat.  Carrier Grade NAT requires the use of more then 1 IP address, so it could be that different TCP sessions are being allocated different IP's
2. You may not be using NAT at all, and your provider is providing you with a subnet of IP addresses which are real-world routable.  This would seem somewhat unlikely in a home environment (and indeed there are security implications to it), but not uncommon if requested on business accounts.
3. Its conceivable your router has more then 1 real-world IP address on it and is doing more complex NATTING (similar to carrier grade nat) to overcome some limitations of NAT.

Comment: Clear and concise. You helped a lot of my friends with the same question. Thanks.